# Which hash function does AWS Cognito use to store user's password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Which hash function does AWS Cognito use to store user's password? There is no information about that in the docs or even forum questions.

Comment: You mean how Cognito sign the JWT token?

Comment: No, I mean which hash function are they using to hash the user's password.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=239434 They state they use the SRP protocol

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with password hashing... this protocol is used for authentication exchange information.

Comment: Cognito doesn't share that information. Heck it doesn't even tell you what db it uses to store user details. Maybe it's a security thing.

Comment: Is your real question about [compliance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/compliance-validation.html)?

Answer (score 3):

I submitted this question in the AWS Support center

This is the answer I've got:

> I would like to mention that Amazon Cognito User Pools adopts Secure
> Remote Password (SRP) protocol for user authentication, Cognito
> doesn’t store user password but rather stores verifier that allows
> Cognito to verify user credentials without receiving the password.
> Cognito user pools store user data in Amazon Cloud Directory which
> encrypts data at rest and in transit by using 256-bit encryption keys.
> Please note that Amazon Cognito and Amazon Cloud Directory are
> in-scope for several compliance programs that verify fulfillment of
> compliance requirements.
>
> Since Amazon Cognito is a managed service and the underlying
> implementation can change without notice. So, for that reason we can't
> provide specific implementation details, but rather, Amazon Cognito is
> in-scope for several compliance programs that verify certain controls
> have been met[1]. As we follow strict guidelines to ensure best
> practices and security so, due to the same reason, these details are
> not shared in our public documentation. Also, Cognito follows best
> practices and standards of the Official Internet Protocol Standards,
> and meets standard compliance requirements. Please check the public
> documentation for compliance validation of Amazon Cognito[2].
>
> So as mentioned, Cognito doesn't store passwords, it stores verifiers
> and salt resulting from the Secure Remote Password (SRP) protocol and
> those verifiers are encrypted with AES 256 encryption. The password
> verifier is derived from a hash of the salt and password. I'm
> attaching a link as reference to SRP protocol [3] (refer section 3 of
> RFC2945).
>
> Cognito is also compliant in accordance with other standards (PCI DSS,
> HIPPA, ISO & C5) and I can confirm sensitive Cognito data is stored in
> AES-256 encrypted format.